# Jira Plugin link HTML to plugin functions

Tags: java, html, plugins, hyperlink, jira

I searched for some answers on stackoverflow and atlassian but so far didnt find anything useful for me. Maybe I'm just asking the wrong questions, but here my situation:

Currently I am writing a Jira TabPanel Plugin, where data of an issue is displayed in the tabpanel. So far everything works fine. I now want to link from the HTML (or JavaScript) of my TabPanel back to my plugin to call an export function, that can save the data in specific formats.

I have no idea how i can do this. My first guesses were that there is a Button you can create from the Java Jira code with a linked ActionListener or some JavaScript that calls the functions for you. But I have not found anything useful for me so far.

Can anyone give me some Information if and how you can do this and maybe some example? I am very thankful in advance.

Regards
Chris

Comment: Why does it has to be a part of the tab panel? Can't you just provide a jira web action?

Comment: Ok now i know that web action might be the right thing to use. But it doesnt have anything to to with tab panel.

Comment: Not with the tab panel, but with the issue. You can pass the issue id e.g..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was Jira webworks. But apparently all Tutorials are a bit vague at some points. I recommend using the atlassian example code that they provide. It is much more useful than any tutorial out there including their own.

JiraWebActionSupport is very important (implement a class deriving from it for example) where you define http responses and/or the use of a velocity script in the doExecute(). All methods from that class can be called from the velocity script by "$action.myMethod()". This is also possible with other fields though i guess a String return type or simple return types are the only usable types.

These were for me the relevant problems/questions. I hope someone else will find this useful.

Regards
Chris